# Set up OS X keyboard to function like OS X within Windows

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-layout

I'm not often in Windows, but when I am, I would like the keyboard to emulate the basic functions within OS X. For example:

1. <kbd>Option</kbd> key combinations set special characters
2. <kbd>Option</kbd> + arrow keys does text navigation (jumps between words/lines/paragraphs)
3. Ideally, use the Super key combination for basic functions (copy, paste, close window, minimize/hide, etc.)

Is there a setting like this handled within Windows? Or a plug-in that performs the same function?

Answer (score 0):

Your options will be rather limited, and your best choice may be to utilize [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/):

> AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language. And if you're really interested, here's a great video about it [here](https://youtu.be/lIFE7h3m40U?t=2m50s).
>
> You can use AutoHotkey to:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks.
>     You can write a [mouse or keyboard macro](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm) by hand or a macro recorder.
> - [Remap](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
> - Create [hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Essentially any key, button or combination can become a hotkey.
> - [Expand abbreviations](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
> - Retrieve and change the [clipboard's contents](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm).
> - Convert any AHK script into an [executable file](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) that can be run on computers where AutoHotkey is not installed.
> - Don't know where to start or how to fix your script? Join the friendly [AutoHotkey community](https://autohotkey.com/boards/) and ask for help

([Source](https://autohotkey.com/))